# Windows phone can not download updates

Tags: update, insider-preview

My lumia 630 is running windows phone 8.1 version **8.10.14234.375** . I signed up to recieve
windows 10 through windows Insider app. However due to some problem update would always fail
after 15-20% (error 801881d0). After retrying for 3-4 times the update would again start from
0% instead of resuming.

To avoid bandwidth overhead and slow download process, I setup squid (3.3.8) proxy on my linux machine. Squid has been caching properly. However although now update downloads lightning fast to my windows phone but only upto 40%. After that it again starts from zero.

A close inspection of squid logs showed that windows update is always failing on a '.cab' file
which around 300 MB in size.

> 1444334340.611 247394 192.168.0.104 TCP_HIT_ABORTED/206 31657152 GET http://wp.ds.download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/dflt/2015/09/microsoft.mainos.production.spkg_b0b882ca68291b814d6445713c005aba352423a7.cab - HIER_DIRECT/115.112.5.28 application/octet-stream

Please help. I have this file cached in my squid. But the windows phone simply would not
download it instead throws the same (801881d0) error.

Comment: Have you tried a hard reset before updating the phone? Might help

Comment: Yes, I already did that. But no help.

Comment: Hey I have a similar issue but I'm behind a restrictive institutional proxy. I have always had the same issue downlading updates, even before joining the insider program. Would you share you squid conf?